# Question about diode connected transistor (BJT) with current source

Tags: transistors, current, bjt, npn, current-mirror

I'm trying to find ΔV for this circuit, but I'm having a bit of trouble doing so.  I think the current on the right BJT will be n times greater than the left, but I'm not sure about that either.  It looks like a current mirroring circuit to generate a ref voltage that's stable with temperature, but I'm still unsure how to find ΔV.

[image]

Comment: In theory both Q’s will have 0 differential Voltage if identical but differential  temperature effects on  Vbe will make a difference. There is no mirroring here but assumed Io’s are perfectly matched.

Comment: The current in both will be \$I_0\$ - how could it be anything else?

Comment: Please provide additional context for the circuit in question. To what does size(A) and size(nA) refer?

Comment: This technique is used in many semiconductor temperature sensors by using the same transistor time multiplexed between two currents.

Comment: Why did you remove the schematic? The question and my answer refer to components, voltages and currents in the schematic, so removing the schematic makes those references unintelligible.

Comment: OK. now you have completely changed the circuit. Before the currents were identical, but the transistor sizes were different. Now, the transistor sizes are (presumably the same) but the currents are different. Please don't change a question after it has been answered. Reverting to previous status. If you want to ask a different question, make it a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have done my math correctly, to a very good approximation,

$$\Delta V \approx \frac{kT}{q} ln(n) = V_T ln(n)$$

where

- k is Boltzman's constant
- T is the absolute temperature in Kelvins
- n is the ratio between the reverse saturation/leakage currents of the two "diodes".
- q is the charge of an electron
- \$V_T\$ is the temperature equivalent voltage

Thus, the output voltage will quite accurately reflect the absolute temperature.

The derivation I used is as follows:

For a silicon diode, (and approximately for a diode connected silicon transistor)

$$I_d = I_s(e^{\frac{qV_d}{kT}}-1) \approx I_se^{\frac{qV_d}{kT}} $$

Since the diodes have the same current,

$$I_{s1}e^{\frac{qV_{d1}}{kT}} \approx I_{s2}e^{\frac{qV_{d2}}{kT}}$$

Taking logarithms on both sides

$$ln(I_{s1}) +\frac{qV_{d1}}{kT} \approx ln(I_{s2})+\frac{qV_{d2}}{kT}$$

Rearranging gives

$$ln(\frac{I_{s1}}{I_{s2}}) \approx \frac{qV_{d2}-qV_{d1}}{kT}$$

$$kT \cdot ln(n) \approx q\Delta V$$